# Name of story where people start breathing at the same time when about to die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story where the protagonist notices that people who breathe at the same time shortly die together. This is the major theme of the story.
It was probably a sci-fi or horror genre and I would have read it in an anthology or story collection book, rather than a magazine.
I'd say would be an older story (50s, 60s, 70s) because it was written with the feel of early sci-fi stories.
I'd love to read it again if anyone recognises it. Sorry I can't provide more detail.

Comment: I remember this well from Omni magazine.

Answer (score 19):

The title is [**"Deep Breathing Exercises"**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1032367) by Orson Scott Card.  It was originally published in Omni Magazine in July 1979. This is the only copy that I could find online ["Deep Breathing Exercises"](http://www.williamflew.com/omni10d.html).

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image]