# Short story: what happens when everyone in a room goes silent?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

40 or 50 years ago I read a story (possibly not actually sci-fi) that referred to a moment when everyone in a room stopped talking. Such moments were actually a remembrance of another world or spiritual state that was generally ignored during ordinary life (and chatter).

I can't remember much but I think the story was narrated (or explained toward the end) by an alien observer who remarked that this type of silence was when human beings remembered an earlier/truer aspect of human nature. So it probably was sci-fi, though it might have been a very short plot focused on this one theme.

Comment: There have been several stories on that theme, so anything else you can remember about the one you read could be helpful.

Comment: @SQB As far as I know, every story on that them has been science fiction or fantasy, and so definitely on topic here. For example, "The Silence" by A. Bertram Chandler.

Comment: Orson Scott Card wrote a short story early in his career about moments when every person within earshot had their breathing slowly align together and [spoiler] it meant they were all about to die together. Narrator figured it out, but I don't remember what happened next. Probably not what you were thinking of.

Comment: @AlexM if I remember correctly, he noticed his own breathing synchronising with a TV anchorman saying something about a Chinese (?) nuclear missile crisis. Then he realises that *everybody else* in the room is synchronising too.

Comment: @user14111: I found The Silence listed here: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?82378    Is there a way to get an excerpt?

Comment: @Martin You can read "The Silence" at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Amazing_Stories_v33n02_1959-02/mode/2up

Comment: Well, that was a good story. The 20-minute cycle rang a bell, so I thought for a while this was the answer. But I distinctly remember something un-sinister about the silence in the one I read ages ago, like a recurrent opportunity to remember something halcyon in humanity's past or maybe just the sense of unity of all humans. Maybe the 20-minute cycle is a clue to the story I'm seeking, but my initial recollection is that the silence was spontaneous at random intervals.

Comment: The story @AlexM is thinking of is Card's "Deep Breathing Exercises"  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129765/name-of-story-where-people-start-breathing-at-the-same-time-when-about-to-die